# Finding smallest equivalent partitioning of integer sequence? (Voting weights)

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, combinatorics, number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Let $U^N$ be the set of all finite sequences of nonnegative integers of length $N$.

Given $u = (u_1, u_2, ..., u_N) \in U_N$ we say the *total* of $u$ is $\sum_{i}(u_i)$

Let $S^N$ be the set of all partitionings of $1, 2, ..., N$ into $2$ partitions - let's label them $A$ and $B$.  (It follows $S^N$ has $2^N$ elements)

Let $Z$ be the 3 element set of integers $-1, 0, 1$ (ie The range of the sign function)

We define a function $F: U^N, S^N \to Z$ as follows:

Given $u = (u_1, u_2, ..., u_N)  \in U_N$ and $s = (A,B) \in S^N$:

$F(u,s) = \text{sign}{(\sum_{a \in A}{u_a} - \sum_{b \in B}u_b)}$

(That is, informally, we split the sequence of integers into two groups and add them up, if the first is less than the second the result is -1, if they are equal it is 0, if the first is greater than the second it is +1.  Think of the "electoral college" voting system in the USA.)

We define an equivalence class $E$ over $U_N$.  Two members of $U^N$, $p$ and $q$, are equivalent under $E$ iff $\forall s \in S^N: f(p,s) = f(q,s)$

We want a function $L: U^N \to U^N$ such that $L(u)$ is the member of $E(u)$ with the lowest total.

Some examples:

```
L(42) = (1)
L(42,42) = (1,1)
L(100,10) = (1,0)
L(100,101) = (0,1)
L(100,101,100) = (1,1,1)
L(100,101,100,100) = (2,3,2,2)
```

How can we calculate $L(u)$?  (Also, is $L$ unique?)

(Obviously as scalar multiples share a class in E, we could first divide through by the GCF of the $u_i$s, resulting in a new sequence that has no common prime factor, but there is more to do as shown by the example as 101 is prime.)

Any ideas?